# Web scaping of a detailed page

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am currently busy with a web scraping of a car data-set using this website - https://www.marktplaats.nl/l/auto-s/p/1/#f:10882

My issue is that interesting parts for my analysis - transmission, type of engine, price, etc - are located on the more detailed page - https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-s/volkswagen/m1547281937-volkswagen-polo-1-0-tsi-highline-beats-edition-navi-xenon.html?c=df2f21f683612b45d62c413c0ca719df&previousPage=lr

I have been successful with scraping information from a general pagination, however have no clue how to iterate and scrape necessary field for me on the detailed page.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Could you provide your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to go through the first webpage to find all the url for each car. Then downloading the car detail and parsing it one by one. I've used `bs4` package (beautifulsoup).
The code below need to be adapted to your needs, but the ideas are here :

```
import requests
import bs4

url = 'https://www.marktplaats.nl/l/auto-s/p/1/#f:10882'

def downloading_and_parsing_url(url):
    # Downloading the webpage as text 
    txt = requests.get(url)
    # Parsing the webpage
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(txt.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup

soup = downloading_and_parsing_url(url)
soup_table = soup.find('ul', 'mp-Listings mp-Listings--list-view')

for car in soup_table.findAll('li'):

    # Finding the url for each 'car'
    link = car.find('a')
    sub_url = 'https://www.marktplaats.nl/' + link.get('href')

    # Downloading each url
    sub_soup = downloading_and_parsing_url(sub_url)

    # Finding the 'div' with id 'car-attributes'
    sub_soup = sub_soup.find('div', {'id': 'car-attributes'})
    for car_item in sub_soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'spec-table-item'}):
        key = car_item.find('span', {'class': 'key'})
        value = car_item.find('span', {'class': 'value'})
        print(key.text, value.text)
    print('\n')
```

And the output

```
Merk & Model: Lako
Bouwjaar: 1996
Uitvoering: 233 C
Carrosserie: Open wagen
Kenteken: OD-31-VD
APK tot: 29 juni 2020
Prijs: € 7.500,00


Merk & Model: RAM
Bouwjaar: 2020
Carrosserie: SUV of Terreinwagen
Brandstof: LPG
Kilometerstand: 70 km
Transmissie: Automaat
Prijs: Zie omschrijving
Motorinhoud: 5.700 cc
Opties: 

Parkeersensor
Dodehoekdetectie
Elektrische achterklep
Metallic lak
Panoramadak
Radio
Mistlampen
Adaptive Cruise Control
Keyless entry
Airconditioning
Boordcomputer
Bekleding leder
Stoelverwarming
Trekhaak
Elektrische ramen
Climate control
Emergency brake assist
Isofix
Alarm
Spraakbediening
Navigatiesysteem
Elektrische buitenspiegels
Traction-control
...
```